# Why Pycharm can find my module,but can't run it?

Tags: python, pycharm

I am a novice about Python and Pycharm.  I followed the tutorial wrote the code below:

[image]

This code can run well on IDLE. But can't run in Pycharm.

I searched online. The answers I found are about Pycharm interpreter setting. My interpreter setting is good.  It can find the module.  But when I run it, There are exceptions.
I spent several hours try to solve this problem, still don't know why.

Comment: could you provide the error message including the exceptions?

Comment: Please do not post images of your code.   Pasting your code into your question will make it easier for the community to assist you.

Comment: the error message said: name 'Frame' is not defined

Comment: Change your import to 'Tkinter' and try running your code again.

Comment: The Tkinter is for Python2.x.   I use Python3.7.   If I change it. The error message said:No module named 'Tkinter'
name 'Frame' is not defined

Comment: @kenlukas I agree with you 99% of the time. In this instance, the image of the IDE actually helped me identify what was wrong! But you're right, 99% of the time it is much better to have copy-pastable code in your question!!!!

Comment: @kenlukas   Thanks for your help. This is the first time I asked question here. I don't know this before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your filename to **somethingelse.py**

*EDIT (with a better explanation:)*

What is happening here is that OP is trying to `import tkinter`. However, since they have named their file "`tkinter.py`," the interpreter thinks that this is the module OP is referencing. For this reason, OP is not getting the desired results, and instead is getting an error about missing attributes.

This probably worked for OP in the IDLE environment, because IDLE allows you to execute the code from within the environment as if you were in a terminal. Pycharm was trying to have the Python interpreter execute the .py file that OP had pulled up.

More information about how Python's import system works can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html

Comment: You can't. If you do that, import statements will resolve to your module, not to the module you want to import.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wasted lot of time.

Comment: @KaiyangLi correct, you're confusing the interpreter!